# material-ui fab href does not add baseurl

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, floating-action-button

In a React 16 application that uses material-ui. I have this FAB

```
<Fab color = "primary" aria-label = "Add" className = {classes.fab}
     size = "small" href = "/technology/new">
    <AddIcon/>
</Fab>
```

The application is configured to use `"metro"` as base URL. so all routes and `<NavLink>` append metro to the link. example `"/dashboard"` becomes `"metro/dashboard"`.

The problem is that `<Fab>` does not append metro to the link. How Can I fix this?

Comment: Fab would default to use a normal a tag underneath, so it would not get any of this additional logic. You can replace the base component used by the FAB by assigning it to the FABs component prop. You could assign `component={Link}` and then use `to="/technology/new"`

Comment: It would be easier to catch up if you reproduce this on codesandbox

Comment: @JacobSmit I don't understand. you mean <Fab to = "/technology/new" component={Link}> with Link is Link} from "@material-ui/core"; Fab does not have a "to" attribute.

Comment: @hgb123 I'm using ConnectedRouter to setup the base url, the code will be too much if I included how the project is setup.

Comment: You would want to use Link from `react-router-dom`, sorry, not the one from MUI.

Comment: <Fab color =  href="/technology/new" component={Link}> <AddIcon/> </Fab> does not work. it says: "index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`."

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to create an example: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cngowu?file=index.tsx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cngowu?file=index.tsx). This would be the preferred way to combine the MUI components with logic from external components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material UI does not connect with React Router (or other routing solutions) automatically.

Material UI does provide away to use its component styling while using external components for functionality, this would allow you to use React Router DOM's Link component as the base for Material UI's Fab component.

This is achieved by setting the `component` prop of the Fab component (most of Material UI's components have this prop). The properties of the passed in component should be available for assignment directly on the Fab component (see Example).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { Fab } from '@material-ui/core';

interface AppProps { }
interface AppState { }

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter 
        basename="test"
      >
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/b" render={() => <div>B</div>} />
          <Route path="/a" render={() => <div>A</div>} />
          <Redirect path="*" to="/a" />
        </Switch>
        <Fab component={Link} to='/a'>A</Fab>
        <Fab component={Link} to='/b'>B</Fab>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Runnable Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cngowu?file=index.tsx

Comment: Perfect now it working great. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle click event of `Fab` and programmatically navigate using `history.push()`

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  alert("already in here")
  // history.push('/technology/new')
}

return (
  <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={handleClick}>
    <AddIcon />
  </Fab>
)
```

Demo codesandbox below

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 0):

With MUI 5+ and react-router-dom 6+ you can wrap your FAB component with the react-router-dom Link component.

```html
<Link to="/your-path">
  <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add">
    <AddIcon />
  </Fab>
</Link>
```

Comment: This creates both <a> and (its nested) <button> elements, doesn't it?